# In Jekyll can I pass a reference to a site data set in front matter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a layout used for the home page for different sections on my Jekyll site.  On each of these pages I would like to have links to each item in the section, the details of which are stored in a YAML file in the site `_data` directory.  My aim is to have the name of the site data variable in the section page front matter and pass this into the layout for rendering.  For example:

**Page Front Matter**

```
---
sectionItems: site.data.sectionItems.awesomeSectionItems
---
```

...which is passed to the section home layout...

**Section Home Layout**

```
{% for item in page.sectionItems %}
    // Work with section item...
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the site nothing appears.  How would I go about doing this?  I have also tried an include but this also does not work.  I would like to avoid adding the for loop to each page, plus I would like the links to appear beneath the main content section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use variables in front matter. You will have to use a content variable like `{% assign sectionItems = site.data.sectionItems.awesomeSectionItems %}` and then loop with `{% for item in sectionItems %}`.

Comment: But what if I want to make a layout and just provide data for some of it's sections(without hardcoding data it a page)

Comment: Sorry @kinqe the comment formating is not appropriate for an answer. You'd better rephrase you question.

Comment: This only works on the template level, the sectionItems would be the same on every page.